# Unity 3D Audio crackling

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm loading (local or from web) 6 stereo audio files that play in sync.
They do play synchronized, thanks to the PlayScheduled capability.

```
Ch1_Master.PlayScheduled(AudioSettings.dspTime + 1);
```

What I can't solve and that's why I came here is the crackling in the audio.
I tried to change with DSP buffersize, but without success. I even created several buttons to change between 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, but although some of them could improve, did not solve at all.

```
public void SetBufferSize(int bufferSize)
{
    AudioConfiguration config = AudioSettings.GetConfiguration();
    config.dspBufferSize = bufferSize;
    AudioSettings.Reset(config);
}
```

I tried both Mac and Android builds. The problem also occurs inside Unity runtime.

I put each audio directed to a specific mixer group. 6 groups + 1 master group.

Is there something else I can try?